# Problema com Media Query

Tags: html, css, layout-responsivo, media-queries

pessoal alguém sabe como eu posso especificar um Media Query pra cada dispositivo ? eu estou tentando deixar o do iphone 6, 7 e 8 de um jeito e nos mesmos celulares só que versão Plus eu estou mudando pra se adequar no layout só que não vai, sempre um acaba passando por cima do outro e fica riscado como vocês podem ver, alguém sabe como posso usar os dois ?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2):

**Resumo**
Vamos supor que a largura da tela do dispositivo tem `667px`. As duas `media queries` serão atendidas. Como a `media querie` de maior `max-width` esta depois da de menor `max-width` ela esta sobrepondo, isso por convenção do `CSS` o que for declarado depois irá sobrepor o que foi declarado antes.

**Solução**
Basta inverter as `media queries` de posição, ou seja, primeiro você declara a `media querie` de maior `max-width` e depois a de menor.

**Exemplo:**

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 736px){
  .titulo{
    color: red;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 667px){
  .titulo{
    color: blue;
  }
}
```

```html
<h1 class="titulo">
  Teste
</h1>
```

Os dois `media queries` continuam sendo atendido pelo dispositivo, mas dessa vez quem prevalece é o de menor `max-width` porque esta depois.